# How do I follow these "makefile" instructions?

Tags: makefile

I am a beginner of Linux. I don't know to handle the following instructions, please teach me in details.

The instructions are below:

1. Go to the `mmed-release-0.1/src/`.
2. Modify the makefile to set appropriate PATHs for Vlfeat, Cplex, GSL Cblas.
3. To compile, type:

   ```
   make
   ```

Compiled mex files are put in `./bin/`

1. Compile `LibSVM` by going to the source directory and type:

   ```
   make
   ```
2. Open Matlab, change directory to: `./src/`.
3. Change the paths to HMMall and LibSVM, and run:

   ```
   m_setup
   ```

Matlab might complain about name conflict of assert. This is the problem of Kevin Murphy’s HMM. Just ignore it.

Comment: And now you would have to tell us, what it is exactly, that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Go to the `mmed-release-0.1/src/`.

That means in a shell you should change directory (`cd mmed-release-01/src/`) to the mentioned directory. That might be in a folder created, when you unpacked the archive that contained Matlab.

> 2.Modify the makefile to set appropriate PATHs for Vlfeat, Cplex, GSL Cblas.

In a file called "Makefile" in the directory `mmed-release-0.1/src/` there should be variables that contain the location of the libraries "Vlfeat", "Cples", and "GSL Cblas". Since Matlab doesn't know how your system is configured you might have to set those library paths yourself. However you can install them with the Ubuntu package manager and then the linker should normally know where they are.

> 3.To compile, type: make

In a shell (e.g. gnome-terminal) cd into the directory where the `Makefile` is located and execute make by typing "make" and pressing enter.

> Compiled mex files are put in `./bin/`

The result of `make` can then be found in the subdirectory called `bin` of the directory where the `Makefile` is located.

> 1.Compile `LibSVM` by going to the source directory and type: make

Change directory to the root of the "LibSVM" library and make it as in the above step 3.

> 2.Open Matlab, change directory to: `./src/`.

Really self explanatory.

> 3.Change the paths to HMMall and LibSVM, and run: m_setup

That one I don't really get. Either you have to run the script `m_setup` in Shell or in Matlab. I assume, just like in the `Makefile` you have to change the respective paths in the file `m_setup` to the right location of the libraries "HMMall" and "LibSVM"